# Catching 302 error and then redirecting in backbone.js sync method override

Tags: redirect, backbone.js, coffeescript, synchronization, http-status-code-302

What I want to do is catch a 302 error which means a user is not logged in, and then redirecting that user to the login page of the website.  Here's my backbone.js sync override right now:

```
parentSynchMethod = Backbone.sync
Backbone.sync = (method, model, success, error) -> 
  try
    parentSynchMethod.apply(Backbone, arguments)
  catch error
    window.location.replace("http://localhost:8080/login")
```

The 302 error is definitely happening, I can see it in the network view when I inspect the page using google chrome.  However, when I set a breakpoint, it never goes inside the catch, and the error argument is undefined.  Is this because 302 is not a real error(it's yellow when I view the status of the response, instead of a usual red for errors, or am I messing up the code somewhere.

Answer (score 10):

The default `Backbone.sync` doesn't raise an exception when the AJAX request returns an error condition (and yes, 302 is an error), it leaves the error handling to `$.ajax`. The default `sync` [looks like this](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1315):

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
  // A bunch of bureaucratic setup and what not...

  // Make the request, allowing the user to override any Ajax options.
  return Backbone.ajax(_.extend(params, options));
};
```

and `Backbone.ajax` is just `$.ajax`; note that the above is the current master branch of Backbone, the currently released version uses `$.ajax` directly.

What you want to do is replace `Backbone.sync` with something that always forces an error handler like this:

```
error: (xhr, text_status, error_thrown) ->
    if(xhr.status == 302)
        window.location.replace('http://localhost:8080/login')
    else
        # call the supplied error handler if any
```

Something like this should do the trick:

```
parentSynchMethod = Backbone.sync
Backbone.sync = (method, model, options) ->
    old_error = options.error
    options.error = (xhr, text_status, error_thrown) ->
        if(xhr.status == 302)
            window.location.replace('http://localhost:8080/login')
        else
            old_error?(xhr, text_status, error_thrown)
    parentSyncMethod(method, model, options)
```

If you're using the master branch of Backbone (or reading this after `Backbone.ajax` is in the released version), then you could replace `Backbone.ajax` with something that forces an error handler as above and leave `Backbone.sync` alone.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and your solution almost works.  I'm getting a 200 status for xhr.status.  It's only one application/json file that's throwing the 302 error and the initiator method is jquery.min.js if any of that helps.  EDIT: It's also being thrown on a POST.

Comment: @prashn64: I'm not seeing anything get thrown and I can get a 302 in `xhr.status`. You've taken this up elsewhere and getting things sorted out, correct?

Comment: Ahh, yes, I decided to do things a bit differently using google app engine routes, I'll explain my solution next week.